# ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on a field, while running automated test but I get this error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input id="artistNominee010" type="checkbox" class="rock-artist-checkbox"> is not clickable at point (967, 601). Other element would receive the click: <span class="rock-artist-toggle-icon"></span>
```

Here is my line of code  that tries to access the attribute:

```
select_nominee = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'artistNominee010'))).click()
```

This is the DOM structure of the page:

```html
<input id="artistNominee010" type="checkbox" class="rock-artist-checkbox">
<label class="rock-artist-label" for="artistNominee010">
<span class="rock-artist-photo-wrap">
<img class="rock-artist-photo" alt="" src="/images/artist-photos/nominee010.jpg"></span>
<span class="rock-desktop-hide rock-artist-name">John Doe</span>
<span class="rock-accessible-text">select John Doe</span>
<span class="rock-artist-toggle-icon"></span></label>
```

From the site, this is the element that is clickable, but i can't select it directly as other elements contain the same class name with different nominees, the id is unique.

```html
<span class="rock-accessible-text">select John Doe</span>
```

is there anyway to do something like this:

```html
select_nominee = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'artistNominee010').class('rock-accessible-text')).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of presence, wait for the element to be clickable

```
select_nominee = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'artistNominee010'))).click()
```

Because the element can be present in the DOM, but not yet clickable (if obstructed by another element, which is probably in your case).

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element instead of [`presence_of_element_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='artistNominee010']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='artistNominee010']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix this, in a very simple way, as shown below:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys

select_nominee = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'artistNominee010'))).send_keys(keys.Keys.SPACE)
```

for reference visit [Selenium: Element not clickable … Other Element Would Receive Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44222266/10798837)