# Scrolling task of Selenium is not worked for me in Python environment

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, web-crawler, infinite-scroll

I want to write a script with adjustable speed. I want to scroll the page into a specific height of the page. I used `window.scrollTo` as follows:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 10)")
```

Although there is no error, after running, we cannot see any change in scroll position. Could you help me, please?

Comment: which OS and Browser you are using?

Comment: Actually, Windows 10 and Firefox 83.0 (64-bit).

Comment: Try : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290451/selenium-python-unable-to-scroll-down

Comment: I checked this link before. It could not help me.

Comment: Also, the scroll bar can be accessed by this code:
src = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div")

Comment: The problem was solved by implementing a new approach. You can see it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved for me by the code as follows:

```
src = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = (0,10)", src)
```

Comment: never use that kind of a xpath

Comment: Could you explain your reason?

Comment: A UI developer changes div[1] to div[2], your entire xpath will fail. now why would a UI developer change it to div[2] cause there will be business requirement to construct a new div either parallel or in sequence. Always prefer relative xpath

Comment: Thank you dear @cruisepandey for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct, but since you are using too short difference, trying to scroll for 10 pixels only, it's not visible.
Please try giving more significant height, like 100 or more and see if it works.
Or put your script in a loop to make the result more noticeable.

Comment: I checked a wide range of numbers before. This is not my solution.

Comment: Hm, interesting! I wish to know what finally will be the solution!

Comment: I found the solution. Now you can see it below.

Comment: @hamedbaziyad  I see. Congrats! So it was an overflowing element there? Also, it's highly recommended NOT to use absolute xpaths.

Comment: The page I decided to crawl is a popup.
Thank you for your suggestion. In this cased I was forced to use absolute Xpath for some reasons.